# conditional constexpr functions

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I have here the case that a function could potentially be constexpr. Normally one adds the constexpr and use the constant evaluation only if the context allows it. However the following code complaints despite not using it in a constexpr context:

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    friend constexpr bool operator==(const Wrapper& crLhs, const Wrapper& crRhs) noexcept
    {
        return crLhs.m_t == crRhs.m_t;
    }

    T m_t = {};
};
```

Using Visual Studio 2017 15.9.20 this gives 'error C3615: constexpr function 'operator ==' cannot result in a constant expression' when e.g. instantiated for std::string. The information is correct but I am **not** instantiating it in a constexpr context.

```
void f()
{
   bool b;

   Wrapper<int>  a;

   b = a == a; //ok

   Wrapper<std::string> c;

   b = c == c;  //C3615, but not using constexpr context
}
```

I can apply a workaround it by using a member template or drop the constexpr but is there fancy trick here to have the best of both worlds (i.e. constexpr when applicable)?

Comment: `constexpr` does not mean that it is evaluated at compile time (as you already know), but it does mean it must be possible to evaluate it at compile time

Comment: @idclev: I know and it can potentially be evaluated at compile time for certain types. Hence the constexpr. Only not for other types. constepxr is cool that you can also invoke it in a none constexpr context. But not if this errors pops up in above case.

Comment: if you know it then why does it matter that you do **not** use/instantiate it in a constexpr context? Anyhow, it doesnt change the actual question.

Comment: @idclev: this is a simplified case. It's a kind of wrapper; sometimes used for built in types; sometimes for more complex types. For the built in types we use the constexpr evaluation of the equality operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your code is fine. This is a bug in older versions of MSVC.

This bug was fixed in MSVC version 19.22, and compiles without error. Here we can see a side-by-side of the two compiler versions: https://godbolt.org/z/79kXFm

All versions after and including 19.22 compiles it, but Version 19.21 and below incorrectly give you error C3615, even though both of them are set to use C++11.

#### GCC and Clang never had this bug.

The bug was only ever in MSVC, and even very old versions of GCC and Clang compile the code without giving you an error.

#### What should you do?

If possible, you should just move to a newer version of Visual Studio. This is the simplest option to upgrade the compiler, and if you move to a newer version the compiler should receive bug fixes and upgrades. If that's not an option, I would google different ways to upgrade just the compiler itself. This [might be helpful](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/side-by-side-minor-version-msvc-toolsets-in-visual-studio-2019/).

Comment: FYI `/std:c++11` doesn't work (compiler complains). It works starting from argument `/std:c++14`.

Comment: How should I tell it to use C++11 when compiling?

Comment: VS introduce this switch after C++11 support was added. In earlier versions you always get newest C++ VS could provide.

Comment: Ok thanks. Transferring to new Visual Studio is not that easy due to the many library dependencies.

Comment: Do those depend on the older compiler version?

Comment: We have to rebuild all the stuff then. Also compiler upgrade must be done company wide.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this being well-formed? I don't see any exception to [dcl.constexpr/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#dcl.constexpr-5) in the standard that would apply here. The exception under the following number 6 applies only to templates and member functions of class templates, but the friend function defined by OP is a non-template non-member function. If there is no exception, the code would be *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*, for the `std::string` instantiation. (Though I guess in practice, if it compiles, the program will behave correctly.)